# Why contact photo have are bad quality/resolution?

Tags: android, bitmap, contacts, photo

Why if i get photo from URI is have are bad quality(1 photo), but in standart Phone app resolution is good(2 photo) and why i have contacts not from my contacts book (3 photo)?
What i need to do?

```
// Display Name
map.put("NAME", (String)cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

// Photo Bitmap
Bitmap tmpPhoto = null;
final ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor sCur = resolver.query(
              ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
              null,
              ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + id + " AND "
              + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"
              + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                        null);
if (sCur == null) {
     tmpPhoto = null;
    }
else
{
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long
                            .parseLong(id));
InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(resolver, uri);
    if (input == null) {
         tmpPhoto = null;
        }
    else {
        tmpPhoto= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
         }
}
sCur.close();
map.put("PHOTO", (Bitmap)tmpPhoto);
```

**My App**

[image]

**Standart App**

[image]

**Theese 3 contacts not from my book**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mostly every app developer wants to preserve his heap, so the results, the actual pictures are copied and trimed/scaled to a lower resolution dimensions so as to be displayed in the `ListView`. when you select that picture the image is then retrieved from its full dimension and displayed(maybe scaled to fit the developer's assisnged space)..

in your case i do not see a picture resolution difference, one is being scaled by android to a smaller display area compared to the other(standart)

Comment: Perhaps you're wrong, i change list view item xml and this is what we have.
Now you see difference?
https://pp.vk.me/c621829/v621829143/2e898/HUfe_N5b3Jk.jpg

Comment: what scale type are you using on your ImageView ? `FIX_XY` or what? if not try `FIX_XY` and see @NK_BRO